# Quand employer l'inversion complexe dans l'interrogation partielle ?

Tags: grammaire, interrogative, inversion, pronom-de-reprise

Comment choisir entre l'inversion complexe (*Où le monde va-t-il ?*) et l'inversion simple (*Où va le monde ?*) dans l'[interrogation partielle](https://fr.wiktionary.org/wiki/question_partielle) ?

Je sais déjà que :

- les inversions sont proscrites après les constructions comme *où est-ce que*, *qu'est-ce que*, *pourquoi est-ce que*, etc ;
- l'inversion simple [est préférable](https://www.academie-francaise.fr/reprise-pronominale-du-sujet-exprime-dans-linterrogation-combien-dauteurs-sont-ils-selectionnes) dans les interrogatives commençant par le pronom interrogatif sujet ***qui*** ou un déterminant interrogatif sujet/attribut (***combien de***, ***quel***) ;
- l'inversion complexe est à privilégier, par souci de clarté, si ***qui*** a pour fonction le CDV (*Qui ton ami avait-il frappé ?* n'étant pas ambigüe, à la différence de *Qui avait frappé ton ami ?*).

Cependant, il reste toute une multitude d'autres cas de figures, notamment les interrogatives introduites par :

- ***où*** (*Où est passé mon porteclé ?* **vs** *Où mon porteclé est-il passé ?*) ;
- ***pourquoi*** (*Pourquoi ont échoué les négociations ?* **vs** *Pourquoi les négociations ont-elles échoué ?*) ;
- ***comment*** (*Comment a pu arriver une telle chose ?* *Comment s'est déroulée la réunion ?* **vs** *Comment une telle chose a-t-elle pu arriver ?* *Comment la réunion s'est-elle déroulée ?*) ;
- des locutions adverbiales de toutes sortes (*Jusqu'où serait allée ta patience?* **vs** *Jusqu'où ta patience serait-elle allée ?*) ;
- les susmentionnés ***combien de*** et ***quel***, lorsqu'ils jouent le rôle de CVD (*Combien de records a battu cet athlète ?* *Quel âge a ton enfant ?* **vs** *Combien de records cet athlète a-t-il battu ?* *Quel âge ton enfant a-t-il ?*) ;

et tant, tant d'autres.

Y a-t-il des règles précises, si complexes soient-elles, qui pourraient apporter de la clarté à tout cela ?

Answer (score 5):

Comme Frank l'a déjà écrit, c'est l'usage qui prévaut. Le registre attendu est aussi important.

J'ai repris toutes les phrases présentes dans la question, mis en gras ce qui me semblait le plus idiomatique à l'écrit, et ajouté des formes qu'on rencontrera plus souvent à l'oral que celle proposées.

***Où est passé** (mon porte-clef)* est presque une forme figée, concurrencée à l'oral par :
***Il est où**, mon porte-clef ?*
*Où mon porte-clef est passé ?* est peu idiomatique. On a un peu l'impression que le porte-clef se déplace de lui-même en choisissant son parcours.

***Pourquoi les négociations ont-elles échoué ?*** est plus idiomatique
*Pourquoi ont échoué les négociations ?* plus rare
*Elles ont échoué pourquoi, les négociations ?* relâché, courant à l'oral
*Pourquoi elles ont échoué, les négociations ?* idem

***Comment une telle chose a-t-elle pu arriver ?*** courant mais un peu soutenu
*Comment a pu arriver une telle chose ?* rare
*Comment ça a pu arriver ?* courant à l'oral

***Comment s'est déroulée la réunion ?*** le plus courant
*Comment la réunion s'est-elle déroulée ?* courant
*Comment la réunion s'est déroulée ?* courant à l'oral

***Jusqu'où serait allée ta patience ?*** courant
*Jusqu'où ta patience serait-elle allée ?* courant
*Elle serait allée jusqu'où, ta patience ?* courant à l'oral

***Combien de records a battu cet athlète ?*** courant
***Combien de records cet athlète a-t-il battu ?*** courant
*Il a battu combien de record, cet athlète ?* courant à l'oral

***Quel âge a ton enfant ?*** soutenu
*Quel âge ton enfant a-t-il ?* rare
***Il a quel âge, ton enfant ?*** très courant à l'oral
***Quel âge il a, ton enfant*** relâché, très courant à l'oral

Comment: Je t'upvotes! :-)

Comment: @Frank Attention, *Comments are used to ask for clarification or to point out problems in the post.* Arrête-ça ou je flague ton commentaire ! ;-)

Comment: Aïe aïe aïe! :-)

Comment: Je pourrais mettre _Comment la réunion s'est déroulée ?_ à l'écrit. _Comment la réunion s'est déroulée ? Hé bien, le chef n'était pas de bonne humeur..._: l'auteur utilise la première phrase pour introduire un récit de ladite réunion, par exemple. Comme s'il répondait à un interlocuteur qui lui aurait posé la question.

Answer (score 2):

Oui, la règle précise est que l'usage va compter pour beaucoup ici. En général (et comme vous les savez sans doute), l'inversion complexe passe moins bien dans la conversation courante, et paraît plus formelle. En conversation, j'utiliserais préférentiellement l'inversion simple, sauf si ambiguïté. À l'écrit, tout dépend du registre que l'on veut utiliser, mais l'inversion complexe passe beaucoup mieux. À noter que parfois, même l'inversion simple peut laisser la place à des constructions périphrastiques plus idiomatiques.

Mais encore une fois, tout cela est flexible, on est dans la préférence et l'usage plus que dans la *règle*, à mon avis. Parmi *Comment s'est déroulée la réunion?* et *Comment la réunion s'est-elle déroulée?*, aucune tournure n'est à priori bannie par une (quelconque) règle. Dans beaucoup de vos exemples, ce qui me frappe, c'est que les deux tournures sont possibles, et c'est ce qui me fait pencher pour le contexte ou l'usage plutôt que pour des *règles* fixes. Vous avez peut-être déjà trouvé les règles qui existent.