# Confused about the grammer of "Pourquoi Carlos et Marc consultent-ils Hélène?"

Tags: pronoms, interrogative, inversion

Still in the A2 phase and got confused about the above interrogative sentence.

As per my understanding, the "ils" means "Carlos et Marc", doesn't it? But I don't find the grammar definition and more sample sentences about it on the internet.

Also, it seems that the language related question is not easy to find as the programmer ones. Harder to find out the keyword.

Comment: It an *inversion complexe*, it has an  answer in this question [Quand employer l'inversion complexe dans l'interrogation partielle ?](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/53602/358). I haven't found one in English on FL, [here's](https://www.dummies.com/article/academics-the-arts/language-language-arts/learning-languages/french/how-to-form-a-question-in-french-using-inversion-166570/) an explanation in English if needed.

Comment: The answers [to this question](https://french.stackexchange.com/q/11097/358) will also answer yours.

Comment: What are you confused about? The plural or the inversion? The 4th result when you google "French interrogative sentence" explains the example: *Où les enfants sont-ils allés ?* which is fairly similar.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, when "ils" is used, that means there is at least on men in the group so "ils" means "Carlos and Marc"

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).